# Gatsby Image query returns out of order images

Tags: javascript, bash, sorting, graphql

I'm making a Gatsby Image gallery with 650 images.
Images are named sequentially: `1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, ..., 650.jpg`

Then I run this query, which should order them by name:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query ImagesForGallery {
    images: allFile(filter: { relativeDirectory: { eq: "gallery" } }, sort: { fields: name }) {
      edges {
        node {
          childImageSharp {
            thumb: fluid(maxWidth: 270, maxHeight: 270) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              originalName
            }
            full: fluid(maxWidth: 1024) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Then, pictures are returned in this order:
`1.jpg, 10.jpg, 100.jpg, 101.jpg, ..., 2.jpg, 20.jpg, 200.jpg, 201.jpg, ...`

So, the images are not being returned in numeric order, but they are using some sort of pseudo-alphabetical order instead. :(

How can I return them in numeric order OR, how can I rename all images to comply with Gatsby order ?

Edit: The easiest way to test is with 6 pictures named:
`1.jpg, 2.jpg, 10.jpg, 11.jpg, 100.jpg, 101.jpg`

Answer (score 2):

Your almost there, the query `sort` attribute looks to be off.
playing with it in the grapqhl playground i was able to sort using `base`

```
{
  allFile(sort: { fields: [base] }) {
    edges {
      node {
        base
        childImageSharp {
          fluid {
            src
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can do it in gatsby query directly, beceause it's kind of specific.

What you could do, is handle it with javascript after you got the data. I've made some code that handle the job

```
var points = ['1.jpg', '32.jpg', '210.jpg', '11.jpg', '1020.jpg', '101.jpg'];

points.sort((a, b) => split(a) - split(b));

const split = (strNumber) => strNumber.split('.')[0]

// will give
["1.jpg", "11.jpg", "32.jpg", "101.jpg", "210.jpg", "1020.jpg"]
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: This is what I have already done, but I am annoyed that I have to do it. In Windows, Mac, and Ubuntu file explorers, when you sort files by name, it's correct, but when the graphql query executes, it somehow does it differently from all the major OS platforms... Maybe I'll open a Github issue. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Ahhh sorry to hear that, it's been a while i haven't put my hands on gatsby, but did you try to use the Sort  / filter / format on your query ? https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#sort